# Clustered(Multiple Instances) Quartz scheduler Interrupt API not working effectively

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a clustered quartz scheduler (3 running java instances referring to the same DB where quartz tables are present). Below is what I have in my quartz properties file. `org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true`

below is the java code

```
import org.quartz.JobKey;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
boolean interruptResult = scheduler.interrupt(new JobKey(jobName,groupName));
```

Use case :
Case 1 :
Jobs are running in instance 'A' and
when interrupt request comes to instance 'B' its not able to interrupt and `interruptResult` comes as false.

Case 2 :
Jobs are running in instance 'A'
and when interrupt request comes to instance 'A', it does the job perfectly by interrupting Jobs.

Can someone help me ? Am I missing additional configuration for multi-instance (clustered) setup ?

Many thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the Quartz works. When you think of it, a Quartz cluster is a "just" bunch of standalone Quartz instances that happen to share the same JDBC job store. The Quartz instances can come and go as they like and they do not have to register / unregister, there is no central node that keeps track of the current cluster topology and orchestrates the execution of scheduled jobs.

This design has some advantages (e.g. easier implementation, higher reliability, and robustness due to the non-existence of a centralized node/manager) and some disadvantages (e.g. cluster-wide operations such as interrupting of jobs are somewhat trickier to implement, load-balancing is primitive).

To implement your use case, you will have to:

1. Iterate through all your clustered Quartz schedulers and query scheduler to obtain the list of all currently executing jobs on that particular scheduler instance.
2. Find the Quartz scheduler instance that is currently executing your job.
3. Invoke the interrupt operation on the found Quartz scheduler instance.

Since you will have to do remote calls, you cannot use the local Quartz API. I recommend using the Quartz JMX API for this job, or you can use the Quartz RMI API. Both are quite easy to use and there should be enough examples on Google.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this, can you point me to any Quartz JMX API example on how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: @puclanac First you need to make your Quartz schedulers export (register) their MBeans in the JVM's MBean registry. This is accomplished by adding org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true to your quartz.properties. Then you will need to enable remote access to the JVM's MBean server by adding a few sys properties on your Quartz scheduler's JVM's command line. You can find the list in chapter 3.1 in this doc: https://quartzdesk.com/downloads/documents/howto/How%20to%20Enable%20Remote%20JMX%20Access%20to%20Quartz%20Schedulers.pdf. Then you need to implement an app with the above-described logic.

Comment: To remotely connect to the JMX server, obtain the Quartz MBean reference and invoke methods on it, you will need to study Java JMX APIs, see some examples and have a play. This is the interface of the Quartz MBean you will want to retrieve from the registry and whose methods  (getCurrentlyExecutingJobs, interruptJob) you will need to call: https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.3/org/quartz/core/jmx/QuartzSchedulerMBean.html.